# Turn off auto line advancement when commenting in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

In pycharm, when you comment/uncomment out a line, (Ctrl-/), the cursor advances to the next line. Is there a way to turn off the auto advance, so that the cursor stays on the same line?

I've searched the JetBrains webpage, google and the settings in pycharm, but so far no luck.

Thanks,